# Program doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a script that is supposed to display a button and a coloured circle on a webpage. When this button is pressed, it is supposed to change the colour of the circle. There are 3 colours which are supposed to be looped through so they should change, in order, every time I press the button.

The issue is, when i run my code, it simply displays the coloured circle I chose when making the  tag and doesn't change when I press the button.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Traffic Lights</title>
</head>
<body>
   <img id="trafficimg" src="green.jpg"  alt="Change Now!">
   <button type="button" onClick="changelight()"> Change the Lights! </button>
   <script>
      var assets = ["red.jpg","yellow.jpg","green.jpg"]
      var state = 1
      var colour = ""                
      function changelight() {
         if state == 1{
            var colour = "green";
         if state == 2{
            var colour = "orange";
         if state == 3{
            var colour = "red";
      }                                
      if colour.includes("green"){
         document.getElementById("trafficimg").setAttribute('src', assets[0]);
         state=state+1;
         if colour.includes("green"){
            document.getElementById("trafficimg").setAttribute('src', assets[1]);
            state=state+1;
            if colour.includes("green"){
               document.getElementById("trafficimg").setAttribute('src', assets[2]);
               state=state - 2;
            }
         }
      }       
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be helpful to get simple solutions that don't change the code too much if possible, though, any help is much appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: do you see any error on console? if state == 1 this should be wrapped in paranthesis

Comment: Someone has already answered this question for you, but for future reference - whenever your JS code isn't working, your first port of call should be the developer console in your web browser (press F12). This would have shown you a big red error message saying your program has a syntax error.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't know that. I am very new to JS

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the conditions in parenthesis

```
if (state == 1) {
// ^          ^
    colour = "green";
    // no need to redeclare color
}
// missing curly bracket at the end of if statement
```

Working example with state as index for the image array.

```js
var assets = ["https://dummyimage.com/50x50/F00/000000&text=+", "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/FF0/000000&text=+", "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/0F0/000000&text=+"],
    state = 0;

function changelight() {
    state++;                // increment state
    state %= assets.length; // remainder operator for keeping state in range of array
    document.getElementById("trafficimg").setAttribute('src', assets[state]);
}
```

```html
<img id="trafficimg" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/F00/000000&text=+" alt="Change Now!"><br>
<button type="button" onClick="changelight()"> Change the Lights! </button>
```

Comment: I have changed this, thank you for the help. I am new to JS/HTML so I miss a few things.

This solution didn't fix the problem entirely, however.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are multiple errors (actually numerous) errors in your short snippet. BTW, I think you wanted to make this:

```js
var state = 1;
var colour = "green";

function changelight(state) {

    if (state == 1){color = "green";}
    if (state == 2){color = "orange";}
    if (state == 3){color = "red";}


    switch(color){
        case 'green': {document.getElementById("para1").style.background = 'green'; break;} 
        case 'orange': {document.getElementById("para1").style.background = 'orange'; break;}
        case 'red':{document.getElementById("para1").style.background = 'red'; break;}
    }

}
```

```html
<p id="para1" style="background:green;width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%;"></p>
<button type="button" onClick="changelight(1)"> green</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changelight(2)"> orange</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changelight(3)"> red</button>
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. The only issue is that I needed only 1 button which switches between the 3 colours

Comment: Hi, pls accept as answer if this helped dear.